# Select from multiple tables where conditions must be met

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I wanted to see if I can better organize / optimize my code, and so I've been reading more about joins and how you can query / select from two different tables where a certain column matches up in a single query. However, I could not find any documentation on what I would like to do.

**Consider two tables (A , B).**

```
Table A
user_id -- + -- course_id
1       -- + -- 1

Table B
course_id -- + -- project_id
1         -- + --    2
```

**My queries look something along the lines of the following:**

```
$sql_course= mysql_query("SELECT course_id FROM A WHERE user_id = 1") or die(mysql_error());

 while ($course_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_course)) {

                            // Unique course ID
                            $courseID = $course_row['course_id'];

                            $sql_b= mysql_query("SELECT project_id FROM B WHERE course_id=$courseID") or die(mysql_error());
```

So, you see, this is not very easy to explain. I suppose what I'm looking to find out is whether or not there is a way to optimize this code, say, using one query?

Comment: All you need are `JOIN`. Join table A and B using `course_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql_course = mysql_query("SELECT A.course_id, B.project_id FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.course_id = A.course_id WHERE A.user_id = 1 ORDER BY A.course_id, B.project_id") or die(mysql_error());
```

You only need to include `A.course_id` in the select portion if you care about the value.

Comment: Thank you for putting this into easy to use terms. I'm going to check this out now and give it a try myself!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this using joins in SQL.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT project_id FROM B JOIN A on B.course_id=A.course_id WHERE user_id=1
```

There are several types of joins, and depending on the results set you'll need to use different ones.

There is a good examination of what joins are doing here:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.project_id
FROM table_b b
JOIN table_a a ON a.course_id = b.course_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1
```

Whether this will actually give you exactly what you want depends on what you are doing with the data, but hopefully it will give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join to make it as single query. As I understood, you are trying to get `project_id` based on `user_id` and the `user_id` is 1.

There is a foreign key relation between Table A and B. So, you can write query as -

```
Select project_id from A, B where A.course_id = B.course_id and user_id = 1;
```